# Real number relation proof

Tags: calculus, real-numbers

For a given $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$, for all $ w <x$, we have $y\geq w$, then we conclude that $y\geq x$.

My friend proves this using contradiction: Assume that $y<x$ then we can find $u\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $y <u <x$ which contradict the assumption that $y \geq w$ for all $w<x$.

The proof is correct but I still feel something is missing. What if $w \leq y \leq x$ for all $w<x$?

Is there any proof that does not use contradiction for this result?

Comment: The "*missing*" bit: I am not sure what you mean. Under this conditions, the statement you are talking about implies $y\ge x$, and as you state $y\le x$ it means that $y=x$. Is there more to it?

Comment: I think the question "What if w≤y≤x for all w<x?" is at fault at "all": that should be "any" or "some", no? As "What if w≤y≤x for any w<x?"

Comment: no that is all the question. In my problem, I also have $y\leq x$ always hold. The assumption is for every $w <x$, then I get $y\geq w$ and the conclusion is $y\geq x$ (because they do not depend on $w$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the direct (no contradiction) proof: take $z=\frac{x+y}{2}$.

- If $z<x$ we have $y\ge z$ per our assumption.
- If $z\ge x$ then $y=z+(z-x)\ge z$.

This means that we have *proven*, in any case, that $y\ge z$. But then $y=x+2(y-z)\ge x$ follows directly.

Comment: In the first point, if I substitute $z$ then I also get $y<x$ which contradict the assumption $y\geq z$ or $y\geq x$ if substitute $z$ ?

Comment: @HungTran Correct. But you didn't want to use a contradiction in the proof, did you? So I just proceed there, without even attempting to prove that the first case cannot happen.

Comment: I understand the first part, but about the second one. If you have $z\geq x$ then the assumption $x>z$ is violated which is also a contradiction? so in the end you still using contradiction?

Comment: No, in the second part, if $z\ge x$ then it just follows that $y\ge z$. (Add $z-x$ to both sides, for example.)

Comment: But the assumption require that $z <x$ and $z\leq y$, and both your arguments have some violation to that so I am not really sure it works like that.

Comment: @HungTran Not sure what you mean. In the first part, assumption requires $z<x$ and this proves $z\le y$. In the second part, I prove again $z\le y$ using the counter-assumption ($z\ge x$). If $p$ and $q$ are two statements, and if $p$ implies $q$ and $\lnot p$ implies $q$, then $q$ must be true, the elementary logic says! (As long as you accept that, except $p$ and $\lnot p$, there is no third possibility.)

Comment: thanks I got to know one more elementary logic. I only know that if $p \rightarrow q$ then ~q $\rightarrow$ ~p.